# Is there an alternative to initializer lists?

Tags: c++, object, constructor, initialization, initializer-list

I have the classes `SmallClass` and `BigClass`. `BigClass` as a private attribute that is an object of `SmallClass`. I've read about initializer lists, but the problem is that I cannot predict the value I need to pass to the constructor of `SmallClass`. The code looks something like this:

```
class SmallClass {
  public:
    SmallClass(int);
  private:
    int boo;
}

SmallClass::SmallClass(int i) {
  boo = i;
}

class BigClass {
  public:
    BigClass();
  private:
    SmallClass sc; // I guess this calls the constructor (and does not compile)
};

BigClass::BigClass() {
  int foo;
  /* Do stuff. I end up with a "foo" having a non predictable value. */
  sc = SmallClass(foo); /* Is there a way to do something like this? */
}
```

Comment: What is `do stuff`? And why can't the calculation of `foo` go into a small utility function that `does stuff`?

Comment: @StoryTeller I can think of an example - `BigClass` ctor calls some external API, gets back `foo` and `bar`, we want to pass `foo` to `SmallClass` and `bar` somewhere else

Comment: @Kos - That's all good and well. But that's a detail the OP needs to include to let people know they better avoid an answer along those lines. Saves everyone a fair bit of time (including the OP).

Comment: Have you tried creating a function that "do stuff", and then call that for the `SmallClass` constructor in the initializer list? Like `BigClass::BigClass() : sc(DoStuff()) {}`?

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry if the question lacks context. I tried to isolate it to exactly what I'm attempting. `BigClass` has more members, one of them being an object whose state is altered in a random way inside the constructor of `BigClass` (like a deck of cards). The thing is just before setting the value of `foo` I need to read the state of said deck of cards (and change it while reading it).

Comment: If the logic to obtain the `int foo` is really troublesome, you can always allocate the SmallClass dynamically: `std::unique_ptr<SmallClass> sc;`

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an alternative to initializer lists?

Yes. Default member initializer is an alternative for initializer list. However, that is not useful for your case. In fact, it is only useful when the arguments of the constructor *are* predictable.

"Non-predictability" of `foo` is not a problem for the initializer lits; you don't need an alternative. Simply call a function:

```
int get_foo() {
    int foo;
    /* Do stuff. I end up with a "foo" having a non predictable value. */
    return foo;
}

BigClass::BigClass() : sc(get_foo()) {}
```

If *"do stuff"* includes access to members (there are no other members in the example, I assume that it may be a simplification), then you can use a member function to achieve that. However, keep in mind that you may only access members that were initialized before `sc`.

Comment: *"If* 'do stuff' *includes access to members, then you can use a member function to achieve that."* - Er, no, you cannot. I mean, you *can*, if undefined behavior is admissible. Otherwise, calling member functions that access member data prior to running the c'tor is not going to end well.

Comment: @IInspectable It's not UB to access members or call member functions within the constructor (including the member initializer list). But you do need to be careful to only access the members that have already been initialized.

Comment: This is still incomplete. If you propose to call a member function to access non-static class members, you're going to have to explain, which class members are initialized prior to calling `get_foo()`.

Comment: @IInspectable then again, all my answers are incomplete, since I don't describe the entire C++ language. I mention member access, since it might not be obvious that it's possible. I now mention that the member has to be initialized, as that could be overlooked. But I find it obvious that to find out what members are initialized, the programmer has to know the order of initialization. And I'm confident that there exists a separate question and answer for that on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a workaround:

```
class SmallClass 
{
public:
    SmallClass();
public:
    void SetBoo(int value);
private:
    int boo;
};

SmallClass::SmallClass() 
{
    boo = 0;
}

void SmallClass::SetBoo(int value) 
{
    boo = value;
}

class BigClass 
{
public:
    BigClass();
private:
    SmallClass sc; // I guess this calls the constructor (and does not compile)
};

BigClass::BigClass() 
{
    int foo;
    /* Do stuff. I end up with a "foo" having a non predictable value. */
    sc.SetBoo(foo); /* Yes, you can set the boo member */
}
```

Comment: I think that workarounds already suggested in the comments are better.

Comment: When I wrote my workaround there was nothing written. Btw you can think what you want.